# Azure website application settings being overwritten after git deploy and deployment slot switch

Tags: azure, cloud, teamcity

I am deploying multiple sites from a single git repo, which I am achieving by setting an application setting for the website via the azure portal. (The setting is 'Project'='pathtomyproject/myproject.csproj'). I deploy to a staging slot first then do a switch as part of my build process. This works, and the correct web project is deployed.

However after live and staging are switching, this setting disappears for both sites (live and staging). Is this by design or what? I don't use a deployment file, and I didn't want to really mess about with renaming deployment files as part of my build process to reduce fragility.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem whenever Microsoft decided to update my VMs, every time they do an update, they shut down the VMs, do the actual update, and then start the VMs again and reapply the deployment files. That last step would fail if not configured correctly, that's why probably you keep losing your setting files.

I would recommend to use the "Continuous deployment" option from Azure, it is available in the preview portal, and would save you the trouble of redeploying you setting files whenever you lose them, and you don't have to create deployment files too.

Read all about it here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-publish-source-control/